# Install the PyCoral library fails: "No matching distribution found for pycoral~=2.0"

Tags: python, google-coral, pycoral

I just got a Google Coral USB Accelerator and am trying to install it on a Windows 11 machine following the instructions at https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/. I got Python 3.11 from the Microsoft app store and it's working fine. But when I tried installing the PyCoral library using the command

```
python3 -m pip install --extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/ pycoral~=2.0 

I'm getting this error saying the library can't be found.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycoral~=2.0 (from versions: 0.0.4, 0.0.5, 0.0.6, 0.0.7, 0.0.8, 0.0.9, 0.1.0)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for pycoral~=2.0
```

I'm not sure whether I'm asking for the wrong version or if I'm using the wrong repo or if Microsoft has "customized" python. In any case, it seems the installation docs needs to be updated.

Comment: Not familiar with the library, but you are on Python 3.11 and checking https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/pycoral/, they have wheels only up to Python 3.9. [Even on their docs](https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#2-install-the-pycoral-library) they say "*PyCoral currently supports Python 3.6 through 3.9. If your default version is something else, we suggest you install Python 3.9 with pyenv.*"

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Didn't think that a later version would be a problem but ...

Comment: Sigh, I just checked and 3.9 is nearing EoL and doesn't have an installer on the official site. Guess it's time to try installing on an RPi and see how that goes.